# How to render plugin templates in Craft CMS 3?

Tags: plugin-development, templating, controller

I cannot find a way to render templates from a plugin controller in Craft 3. I feel as though I've tried every variation advised online but for some reason this still isn't working.

```
<?php

namespace abc\members\controllers;

class LoginController extends \craft\web\Controller
{
    public function actionForm()
    {
        $this->renderTemplate('abc-members/login.html');
    }
}
```

The plugin handle is "abc-members".

The plugin has a "templates" directory with "login.html".

I've tried the following, with and without the .html extension, but none can find the template:

```
$this->renderTemplate('abc-members/login.html');
$this->renderTemplate('abc-members/templates/login.html');
$this->renderTemplate('abc-members/src/templates/login.html');
$this->renderTemplate('abc/members/src/templates/login.html');
$this->renderTemplate('plugins/abc/members/src/templates/login.html');
```

The following works fine but then I cannot include templates from the installation's main template directory.

```
<?php

namespace abc\members\controllers;

class LoginController extends \craft\web\Controller
{
    public function actionForm()
    {
        \Craft::$app->view->setTemplatesPath(__DIR__ . '/../templates');
        $this->renderTemplate('login.html');
    }
}
```

Any suggestions as to where I'm going wrong? I find the Craft 3 docs are a bit lacking in the whole area of plugin controllers, routing and templates other than in the Craft 2 => Craft 3 upgrade guide.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't specify, but it sounds like you're trying to have the plugin render its templates as a result of frontend requests? If so, you'd need to do:

```
use Craft;
use craft\web\View;

$oldMode = \Craft::$app->view->getTemplateMode();
Craft::$app->view->setTemplateMode(View::TEMPLATE_MODE_CP);
$html = \Craft::$app->view->renderTemplate('plugin-handle/path/to/template');
Craft::$app->view->setTemplateMode($oldMode);
```

If you're trying to mix and match between the normal Craft templates directory and your plugin's templates, you'd need to change the template mode as you bounce back and forth.

c.f.: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/updating-plugins.html#rendering-templates

Comment: Ah, I managed to try just about everything _but_ this. I tried `setTemplateMode(View::TEMPLATE_MODE_SITE)` assuming that `View::TEMPLATE_MODE_CP` was related to rendering templates for routes in the admin control panel, rather than on the public frontend of the site. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

After becoming more familiar with Craft and Yii, I've found a more appropriate solution for my use case. I have a couple of ideal requirements:

1. Templates are stored in a directory within my module or plugin.
2. Templates can be mixed with general application templates (e.g. my module or plugin template can extend from a general site layout template).

It turns out that the [Template Roots](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/template-roots.html) functionality enables this, so it is documented but for some reason I was overlooking this previously.

You can simply register the template root during plugin/module init like so:

```
Event::on(View::class, View::EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_TEMPLATE_ROOTS, function (RegisterTemplateRootsEvent $event) {
   $event->roots['_my_prefix'] = __DIR__ . '/templates';
});
```

Then templates in the defined directory can be rendered using the defined prefix (`_my_prefix` in this case), as though that directory exists in the main templates directory. This means they can be used in any context and extend or include templates in the main directory ‒ desirable for app specific plugins/modules.

Comment: Best solution for me too. Thanks a lot.